# SVN server for Mac OSX

Tags: svn, macos

I used to use Visual SVN on Windows.  Now I am on Mac OSX.

Does anyone know of an SVN server for MAC OSX which is as easy to use as Visual SVN on Windows?  I don't want to be typing in console commands, I'd like a nice and simple UI :-)

Cheers

Comment: +1 because it is a valid question.

Comment: I'm not diss'ing SVN or the question, but switching your OS may also be a good opportunity to consider trying out a different source code control system like a DVCS system like Mercurial or Git.

Comment: i think mac already come with SVN. what you may need is SVN Server GUI (GUI Only).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Mac OSX LION and Snow Leopard comes with SVN Server by default. [An easy tutorial can be found here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-repositories_organizer/articles/SettingupaSubversionRepositoryfromtheCommandLine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010350-CH3-SW1)

Basically you will be using command line (shell) environment. No GUI tool is available.

To create a repository issue this command

```
svnadmin create MyFirstRepository
```

This will create a repository with the above name in the current folder.

The next step is to import a directory. Use this command

```
svn import destination-folder file:///path-to-repository -m "Initial Import"
```

The third step would be to checkout what you just checked in.

```
svn checkout file:///path-to-repository destination-folder
```

Comment: Im my mac its done create repo and checkout by xcode, but how can i checkout via network by other mac ... ?

Comment: @iOSDev that will be a separate networking question that you might ask. My guess is, in Finder, you can click on menu and select connect to server but that is just my guess.

Comment: -1 Because the OP asked for a UI: `I don't want to be typing in console commands, I'd like a nice and simple UI`.

Comment: I can see that everything is installed with my Xcode 5 and SVN.. but how do I navigate to the repo server?  I am on a single laptop and I assume the url would be svn://localhost.. or something like that.. but I am unable to find this out

Answer (score 5):

I know that you want a simple GUI app to install the server, but you can get apache serving your subversion repository with WebDAV authentication really quickly and easily.  Using macports to install all the dependencies and with a few basic changes to the configuration options in apache, you are good to go.

Here is the basic setup (from Macports wiki) : [MacPorts Subversion with Apache](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/Subversion)

The command line is your friend!

Answer (score 4):

Another nice stack for a subversion server can be found at http://bitnami.org/stack/subversion. From the description:

> BitNami Subversion Stack greatly simplifies the deployment of Subversion and its required dependencies. It can be deployed using a native installer, as a virtual machine or in the cloud.

Answer (score 3):

As an aside, it should be noted that Snow Leopard (at least) comes with an SVN server bundled by default.  I believe that Leopard did as well.  Either way, you're far better off just using it instead of rolling your own solution.

Apple's instructions: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/SubversionXcode3/

A slightly more complicated integration:
http://ursecta.com/wp/2009/11/subversion-server-on-snow-leopard-server/

Comment: That link to Apple's instructions is broken. Do they have it posted elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I know you're itching for Visual SVN-alike on the mac, but one of the big reasons you're not getting a lot of answers is that SVN and Apache don't exist by default on Windows (an itch that Visual SVN scratches), but do exist on OSX.

The argument goes like this: if you're savvy enough to be using SVN, then most likely you will either be happy with what OSX has by default (command line!), or you likely have a Linux server somewhere that serves SVN for you.

I recommend a couple of options for you in addition to what everyone else mentions:

1. Keep your existing windows machine as a server for your SVN needs
2. Run a VMWare appliance + VMWare fusion (here are some [Trac+SVN appliances](http://swik.net/appliance+trac))

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/), if you need a comprehensive 3rd-party app.

Until recently I had a simple setup - a local SVN (file) repository on my local drive; then used Xcode's SCM (Source Control Management) windows to manage SVN commands - it's not too bad for most of the day-to-day actions.  Obviously, this is assuming you're using Xcode?

Comment: you probably mean Source "Code" Management lol

Comment: I probably did! But then I looked back at the SCM documentation in Xcode - it says "Source control management systems, ..." -- I knew I'd read it somewhere!

Comment: Apple engineers are weirdos :P

Answer (score 0):

You can [download subversion for OSX](http://www.wandisco.com/download/subversion#osx) from WANdisco.  They also have [uberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com/) which is a web based tool similar to VisualSVN with much more functionality.

Answer (score -1):

While this isn't mac-central per-say, [Warehouse](http://warehouseapp.com/) was open sourced some time ago and might be worth a look. It's a web-based GUI for svn and git repository management.

Answer (score -3):

The server and the GUI are separate components. As for great SVN GUIs, [Versions.app](http://versionsapp.com/) seems to be the favorite.

Editing to add the following additional SVN apps:

http://ciaranwal.sh/2007/10/10/svn-plug-in-for-textmate (TextMate plugin)

https://www.smartsvn.com/

http://www.syncrosvnclient.com/index.html

http://www.zennaware.com/

Comment: -1, he is asking about a server, not a client.  He just wants a server that has a nice graphical interface (similar to Visual SVN - which is a Windows SVN server).

Comment: “a server that has a nice graphical interface” — isn’t everything just a front-end to the command line Subversion program? On Mac OS X, I use `svn` at the command line to both access svn repositories elsewhere, and create them on my machine.

Comment: The problem is with the question, not the answer.

Comment: The problem isn't in the question, the question is quite clear.  I want something like VisualSVN server (Windows) for MacOSX.

Comment: The problem def. isn't with the question.  The problem is with people commenting and answering who actually don't want to *answer* the question, but would like to tell the world how *they* do it and just how smart and right they are.  And no, not all servers are wrappers for the command line.